# Why is ::part() not working for slotted Stencil elements?

Tags: pseudo-element, stenciljs, slot, slots

My HTML:

```
<my-dropdown label="dropdown" size="m" filter="true">
    <select slot="filter" part="myselect">
      <option>One</option>
      <option>Two</option>
      <option>Three</option>
    </select>
</my-dropdown>
```

Inside the my-dropdown components, I have a slot:

```
<slot name="filter" />
```

The css stylesheet is inside the component, and in it, I have defined:

```
my-dropdown::part(myselect) { 
..
}
```

The styles do not apply to the component! Why? Am I not doing it correctly?

Comment: Please remember to accept the answer if it solved your problem - this helps other users know the reliability of the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: Because **it's not meant to work on slotted elements**.

The CSS parts `::part()` pseudo-element selector is used to apply style to elements that are within shadow DOM which use the `part` attribute.

In your example, you have added the `part` attribute to the element `<select slot="filter" part="myselect">` which is in light DOM not shadow DOM.

Note that slotted elements are not actually **moved** to the shadow DOM; their position in the DOM is not affected by the slotting mechanism so they exist in regular light DOM like any other element. They are just *rendered* inside the shadow DOM structure of the parent web component, with both the component's shadow DOM style for that slot ([`::slotted()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::slotted)) and any regular DOM styling e.g. global stylesheet applied.

In order for the `my-dropdown::part(myselect)` selector to work, the element that has the `part="myselect"` attribute would have to be inside the shadow of the `my-dropdown` component - for example:

```js
@Component({
  tag: 'my-dropdown',
  styleUrl: 'my-dropdown.scss',
  shadow: true,
})
export class MyDropdown {
  render() {
    return (
      <Host>
        <div part="myselect">
          <slot name="filter" />
        </div>
      </Host>
    );
  }
}
```